# i в старом алфавите

Tags: алфавит

По каким правилам в русской письменной речи до реформы Луначарского писалась буква i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед гласными и перед «й» (например, *исторія, русскій, Іерусалимъ*);
в слове *міръ* в значении «Вселенная», «общество» (для отличия от слова *миръ* в значении «спокойствие».

Исключение в дореформенном правописании составляли сложные слова, в которых первая часть оканчивалась на и: *пяти*угольникъ, *наи*ужаснѣйшій.